# Soap in Groovy - keep getting NoSuchMethodError

Tags: soap, groovy

Newbie question:

I'm new to groovy & soap , so I might be missing out on something here:

I'm trying to communicate with a very basic web service :

```
import groovy.net.soap.SoapClient
... 
def proxy = new SoapClient("http://soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl")
res = proxy.Method1("ABC", "123");
println (res);
```

It seems the connection works , but when I try to invoke "Method1(..)" , I keep getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getInstance()Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/Invoker;
    at groovy.net.soap.SoapClient.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
```

This is the relevant part of the WSDL:

```
<message name="Method1">
<part name="bstrParam1" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="bstrParam2" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
−
<message name="Method1Response">
<part name="bstrReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
−
<portType name="SoapResponderPortType">
−
<operation name="Method1" parameterOrder="bstrparam1 bstrparam2 return">
<input message="tns:Method1"/>
<output message="tns:Method1Response"/>
</operation>
</portType>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The wsdl seems to show the method is called Method1, not ConversionRate. Could be an error with your test soap service?

Comment: @tim_yates I switched test , because the previous one has a very lobg response time - and I forgot to chane the text. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: two comments, (1) isnt the SoapClient deprecated? (2) try testing the service first with SoapUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it didn't resolve , but I did move to GroovyWS and after a little dependencies hell ,it worked. See [here](http://www.yossale.com/?p=143)

Answer (score 2):

The [help page for Groovy Soap](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+SOAP) says it has been deprecated (on Mar 03, 2008), so probably hasn't had any love for quite a while :-/

It recommends to [use GroovyWS](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS), and that page says that this should work:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules', module='groovyws', version='0.5.2')
import groovyx.net.ws.WSClient

try {
  proxy = new WSClient( "http://soapclient.com/xml/soapresponder.wsdl", this.class.classLoader)
  proxy.initialize()

  result = proxy.Method1("ABC", "123")
  println res
}
catch( e ) {
  e.printStackTrace()
}
```

However, when you run this, you get:

```
[snip]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected <schema> appears at line 0 column 0
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.unexpectedX(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:488)
    ... 54 more
```

I can't see why this WSDL is wrong however...  I'll keep looking